# Android use bold character for part of text

Tags: android

i want to simply use `<b>` for part of text like with `HTML` & `CSS`, my below code is not correct.

```
textEdit.setText("<![CDATA[ <b>"+ "bold text" + " </b> ]]>" + " view other normal text" );
```

Answer (score 8):

Use a **[SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)** to set the substring as bold.

```
    String completeString = "<your complete string here>";
    String subString = "<the substring you want in bold>";
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(completeString);
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            ds.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            ds.setColor(<color that you want>);
        }
    };

    if (completeString.indexOf(subString) > -1)
        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, completeString.indexOf(subString), completeString.indexOf(subString) + subString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    textEdit.setText(ss, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

use below code:-

```
mTextBox.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + Bold text+ "</b>" +  "<br />" + 
            "<small>" + Small one+ "</small>" + "<br />" + 
            "<small>" + Small two+ "</small>"));
```